# proving that $g(x)\in A$ for almost every $x$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $B$ be a (Lebesgue) measurable set with $m(B) < \infty$ and let $g \in L^1(B)$. That is, $\int_B |g| < \infty$. Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a closed set such that $\frac{1}{m(F)} \int_F g dm\in A$ for every $F\subseteq A, m(F) > 0$. Prove that $g(x) \in A$ for almost every $x\in B.$

A hint was the following: let $a \in A^c$ and $r > 0$ be small enough so that the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $a, \overline{B}_r(a),$ is contained in $A^c$. Show it suffices to prove $m(F) = 0$, where $F = g^{-1}(\overline{B}_r(a))$. Show that if $m(F) > 0,$ then $\frac{1}{m(F)}\int_F g dm \in A^c$.

I know that a countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero, so maybe I could obtain the countable union using $F$ somehow? Also, I'm not sure how to show that if $m(F) > 0,$ then $\frac{1}{m(F)} \int_F g dm\in A^c$. How can I conclude that the integral is not in $A$? Should I use some sort of contradiction?

Comment: Are the sets A and B related in some way? Because if they are not we have no information at all about properties of the function g on A. It may not be integrable or not even measurable! Please explain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know that $\overline B_r (a) \subseteq A^{c}$. So is is enough to show that $\frac  1 {m(F)} \int_F gdm \in \overline B_r (a)$. In other words, we have to show that
$|\frac  1 {m(F)} \int_F gdm -a|\leq r$. This is same as $\frac  1 {m(F)} \int_F |g-a|dm \leq r$. But $|g-a| \leq r$ on $F$ (by definition of $F$) so we are done.

Comment: Thanks. For the "it suffices to show that m(F) = 0" part, can't we just write $S^c$ as a countable union of closed balls?

Comment: @user3472 Yes, exactly. That is the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea rather than a proof! ΙIt is a well known facr that almost every point of an integrable function as g is a Lesbegue point. So taking one such point say z and a sequence of sets  $F_{n}\supseteq \left\{ z\right\}$ such that $m(F_{n}$)$\rightarrow$ 0 and hence the lim of the integral is g(z)$\in $ A. ie g(z)$\in$ A for almost every point in B.